# How to allow iOS app to search Rails JSON API?

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, json, api

I have a Rails API I am using as a backend for a Swift iOS app. I want to allow users of the Swift app to search authors and books, and I have API endpoints for "all books" and "all authors."

Do I need to write logic in an API endpoint for search, or is there a standard syntax, something like /api/authors?utf8=✓&q%5Btitle_contains%5D=magic

I have Redis/soulmate installed in the web app for search but not sure how to extend this to an API endpoint.

Thanks for any tips!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**No.** Rails does not have any search utilities built in. Which is due to fact that there are so many possible way to achieve it depending on the requirements.

Simple filtering can be done with params and scoping:

```
def index
  @dogs = Dog.all
  @dogs = Dog.where(status: params[:status].to_sym) if params[:status]
end
```

[There are gems](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/rails_search) which provide full text search with Lucene, Solr, Elasticsearch and many others.

Comment: ok - so with that example - what would the route be, something like: http://localhost:3000/api/books?title=text

Comment: in this case it would be something like `localhost:3000/api/dogs?status=available`. But that really depends on how you implement the routes. You might want to read up on how parameters work in rails http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#parameters

Comment: Sorry I think I misunderstood your comment, but it completely depends on how you choose to implement it. You are the author of your API and Rails does not have an specific options on how to implement search or even what search entails. Look at an api which you find well designed and emulate the routes and then look at what scale you need and then research the possible implementation solutions from there.